# Symfony and Angular application

Tags: angularjs, symfony, fosrestbundle, hateoas

I have SF2 application and AngularJS client.

When I create some item symfony returns `HTTP 201 status`, which means item is created.

And... I want to know ID of this item, or better route to this item. So when I create something I want to return `HTTP 201 status` and also `Location: http://my-app.dev/created-item/{id}` and `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location` headers.

Of course I can create new response and add this headers. But I have to do this in any `createAction` in my controllers.

Is there some way to add this headers automatically to any 201 response after success POST request?

Or maybe I'm thinking in wrong way and should do otherwise?

Comment: Use a `REST` bundle for SF2, like [FOSRestBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html).

Comment: I use it. But it doesn't add this headers.

Comment: You may want to make your REST API support `HATEOAS`, take a look at [BazingaHateoasBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaHateoasBundle) and this [Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/resting-with-symfony/Bv3fTSfaZXI). Also see [this presentation](http://friendsofsymfony.github.io/slides/build-awesome-rest-apis-with-symfony2.html#/4).

Comment: Redirects have their own set of return codes.  So no, you can't return both 201 and 301 in the same response.  And you probably don't wan't to anyways.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a REST API with [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) support.

### What is HATEOAS?

What basically `HATEOAS` does, is automatically add URIs to every resource being returned by your API.

An example for an `HATEOAS`-based response for a call to `http://localhost:8080/api/customers` would be:

```
[{
    "name": "Alice",
    "links": [ {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/customers/1"
    } ]
}]
```

This returns all customers and for every customer the self-linking URI to that customer's resource.

### How to use HATEOAS in SF2?

You can integrate it in Symfony2 using a combination of [`FOSRestBundle`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html), [`BazingaHateoasBundle`](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaHateoasBundle) and `JMSSerializerBundle`.

Your relations (links to resources) can be configured in `XML`, `YAML`, `PHP` or `Annotations`. An example with annotations would be:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use Hateoas\Configuration\Annotation as Hateoas;

/**
 * @Serializer\XmlRoot("customer")
 *
 * @Hateoas\Relation("self", href = "expr('/api/customers/' ~ object.getId())")
 */
class Customer
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    ...
}
```

See [this presentation](http://friendsofsymfony.github.io/slides/build-awesome-rest-apis-with-symfony2.html#/4) for more details.

I've never used this myself, but according to [this Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/resting-with-symfony/Bv3fTSfaZXI), `BazingaHateoasBundle` builds on `JMSSerializerBundle` to generate automatically links and embedded objects for the serialized objects, so you don't need to do anything else.

**Conclusion:** When you create a new item in a `POST` request, return the created item. `BazingaHateoasBundle` will automatically add the URI/route of that item to the response.